# Divisible by 5 or 6

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program where it lists all the numbers between 100-1000 that are divisible by 5 or 6. This is the code I used:

```
public class divisibleBy5and6 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        j = 1; 
        int number = 100;
        while (number < 1001) {
            if (number % 6 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print(number + ", ");
                number++;
                j++; }

            if (j % 10 == 0 && j != 0) {
                System.out.println();
                j++; }
            else {
                number++;
            }
        }
```

I used `int j` to make it so there are 9 per row. This is my output:

```
100, 102, 105, 108, 110, 114, 120, 125, 130, 
132, 135, 138, 140, 144, 150, 155, 160, 162, 
165, 168, 170, 174, 180, 185, 190, 192, 195, 
198, 200, 204, 210, 215, 220, 222, 225, 228, 
230, 234, 240, 245, 250, 252, 255, 258, 260, 
264, 270, 275, 280, 282, 285, 288, 290, 294, 
295, 300, 305, 310, 312, 315, 318, 320, 324, 
325, 330, 335, 340, 342, 345, 348, 350, 354, 
355, 360, 365, 370, 372, 375, 378, 380, 384, 
385, 390, 395, 400, 402, 405, 408, 410, 414, 
415, 420, 425, 430, 432, 435, 438, 440, 444, 
445, 450, 455, 460, 462, 465, 468, 470, 474, 
475, 480, 485, 490, 492, 495, 498, 500, 504, 
505, 510, 515, 520, 522, 525, 528, 530, 534, 
535, 540, 545, 550, 552, 555, 558, 560, 564, 
565, 570, 575, 580, 582, 585, 588, 590, 594, 
595, 600, 605, 610, 612, 615, 618, 620, 624, 
625, 630, 635, 640, 642, 645, 648, 650, 654, 
655, 660, 665, 670, 672, 675, 678, 680, 684, 
685, 690, 695, 700, 702, 705, 708, 710, 714, 
715, 720, 725, 730, 732, 735, 738, 740, 744, 
745, 750, 755, 760, 762, 765, 768, 770, 774, 
775, 780, 785, 790, 792, 795, 798, 800, 804, 
805, 810, 815, 820, 822, 825, 828, 830, 834, 
835, 840, 845, 850, 852, 855, 858, 860, 864, 
865, 870, 875, 880, 882, 885, 888, 890, 894, 
895, 900, 905, 910, 912, 915, 918, 920, 924, 
925, 930, 935, 940, 942, 945, 948, 950, 954, 
955, 960, 965, 970, 972, 975, 978, 980, 984, 
985, 990, 995, 1000,
```

This obviously isn't right because I am missing numbers like `115`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing `number++` twice, this is suspicous. Try to refactor to a `for` loop.

Comment: No odd number is divisible by 6.

Comment: Your problem is that your code is incorrectly formatted (seriously).  Reformat it and things will be much clearer.

Comment: 115 is divisible by 5 though

Comment: haha, you've misled everyone:) again I should say why exactly do you check j != 0? Indeed it's always true.

Comment: @mok - I'm guessing that originally `j` was initialized to zero, and the check was added to prevent an initial newline.  The check was not removed because it didn't create a symptom after the init value was changed to 1.

Comment: @HotLicks> Maybe, anyway it's redundant now.

Comment: In addition to the code issues, your approach is not ideal.  Instead of checking every number, you should construct the list by computing all of the multiples of 5 and all of the multiples of 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the code is incorrectly formatted.  Properly indent it and it becomes much clearer:

```
public class divisibleBy5and6 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        j = 1; 
        int number = 100;
        while (number < 1001) {
            if (number % 6 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print(number + ", ");
                number++;
                j++;
            }

            if (j % 10 == 0 && j != 0) {
                System.out.println();
                j++;
            }
            else {
                number++;
            }
        }
```

Then you can see that the `else` is attached to the second `if`, not the first, so the incrementing of `number` can occur twice.

After that it's clearer that, inside the first `if`, `number` is incremented ONLY if the number is printed.  What you really want is for `number` to be incremented for every iteration, and the best way to assure that is to ONLY increment number immediately prior to the closing `}` of the `while`.

Then you'll realize that the `while(number < 1001) ... number++` loop can be replaced with a more robust `for (int number 100; number < 1001; number++)`, totally removing the incrementing of `number` from the loop body.

When designing a loop it's quite important to keep straight which values are "invariant" in the loop (never change at all), which are simply incremented with each iteration, and which are modified on a more irregular basis.  If you keep these concepts straight then loops are much less intimidating.

Comment: Why exactly do you check j != 0? Indeed it's always true.

Comment: @mok - Well, the above is the OP's original code, just reformatted.  You'd have to ask him that.

Comment: I've asked him too, but I think it's better to update you answer, it's a very trivial mistake that someone like you don't ought to do it.

Comment: @mok - I didn't make a mistake (aside from my original misreading of the problem).  I chose to leave the OP's code unmodified, aside from reformatting it, to illustrate the benefits of correct formatting.

Comment: Obviously you didn't do the mistake, I just say it's better that you also correct this mistake of him.

Comment: @mok - Then I'd have to correct all his mistakes and it wouldn't be his code anymore.

Comment: Ok, as you wish. I always try to correct all the errors or mistakes of the OP in my answers, but it's just my approach and others may find it a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

You need to seperate the number incrementation from the if/else statements. It should happen at each iteration no matter what...

```
int j = 1; 
int number = 100;
while (number < 1001) {
  if (number % 6 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
    System.out.print(number + ", ");
    j++; 
   }
   if (j % 10 == 0) {
     System.out.println();
   }
   number++;
}
```

Comment: `j++` **should** be implemented in the `if` block though, as it's the number of numbers printed.

Comment: Why exactly do you check j != 0? Indeed it's always true.

Comment: Also true. Corrected in answer. Cheers @mok

Comment: Just ran the code without j != 0, and it is the same, you're right. I actually don't remember why I put that in.. At the time I guess I thought it would matter.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that sometimes, you're incrementing `number` twice in each loop.  The first time is if the number is a multiple of `6` or of `5`, and the second time is when you don't print a newline.  This has the effect of skipping numbers, such that consecutive multiples of `5` or `6` won't print, such as your `115`, because it's after `114` and is skipped.  Notice also that other consecutive multiples of `5` or `6` won't print, such as the `126` after the `125`.

Make it clear that you increment `number` only once per loop but removing `number++;` from the `if` and `else` blocks, and unconditionally increment by placing `number++;` at the very bottom of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

remove the first place it says `number++;` after the `System.out.print(number + ", ");`

alter

```
else {
                number++;
            }
```

It does this when you've just printed a newline.

to

```
            number++;
```

It will do this on every loop iteration
`number` should be incremented non conditionally

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class DivisibleBy5and6 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int j = 1; 
        for (int number = 100 ; number < 1001; number++) {
            if (number % 6 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print(number + ", ");
                j++; 
            }

            if (j % 10 == 0) {// j never equals 0
                System.out.println();
                j++; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, For definite loops it's better to use `for` instead of `while`. (makes your code more readable)

As you see you don't get confused this way and increase `number` once and in the right place.

Comment: +1, this last bit is probably the most useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

You had a duplicate `number++` which was executed twice when both conditions were true.
That overjumps some values: now corrected:

```
int j = 1;
int number = 100;
while (number < 1001) {
    if (number % 6 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.print(number + ", ");
        j++;
    }

    if (j % 10 == 0 && j != 0) {
        System.out.println();
        j++;
    }
    number++;
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you check j != 0? Indeed it's always true.

Comment: @mok, i didn't invest more time to optimize foreign code, it solved the task with minimal monetray costs (time invested)  but is not optimal. Feel free top optimize.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class pattern {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int j = 0; 
        int number = 100;
        while (number < 1001) {
            if (number % 6 == 0 || number % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print(number + ", ");
                j++; }

            if (j % 10 == 0&&(number % 6 == 0 || number % 5 == 0)) {
                System.out.println();
                number++;     
            }
            else
            {
                number++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this code.

The mistake in your code is that you are actually incrementing `number` twice so that's why you are missing some numbers.
Good luck :)